# Format output of my bash script to perform ssh operations on it further

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have a file where my script outputs IP and file paths. I want to process that file further where it could automatically ssh to that IP and take file stat of that path from respective IP

```
cat final-list
Node Name: 192.168.1.6 Out-ofSync-Filename: /home/user/nginx/Templates/file1
Node Name: 192.168.1.7 Out-ofSync-Filename: /home/user/nginx/createfile /home/user/nginx/Templates/file3
Node Name: 192.168.1.8 Out-ofSync-Filename: /home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file1 /home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file5 /home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file3 /home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file9 /home/user/nginx/nginx/file12 /home/user/nginx/Templates/file56
```

My script for parsing above file:

```
xargs -n1 < final-list | grep -v "Name:" | grep -v "Node" | grep -v "Out-ofSync-Filename:"

192.168.1.6
/home/user/nginx/Templates/file1
192.168.1.7
/home/user/nginx/createfile
/home/user/nginx/Templates/file3
192.168.1.8
/home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file1
/home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file5
/home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file3
/home/user/nginx/nginx/Templates/file9
/home/user/nginx/nginx/file12
/home/user/nginx/Templates/file56
```

It has IP and respective files(filepaths per IP may increase in future) for which I want to find out last modified time of that file by ssh into that server IP using respective Path.

Comment: I'm noticing that you haven't accepted any of the answers to your other questions.  Consider accepting the most helpful answers. Not ever accepting answers will eventually deter users from engaging with your questions. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply run `rsync` in dry-run mode between some master repository of files and your various servers?  This would tell you exactly what files are not up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from your `final-list` directly and assuming that the remote system is a Linux system:

```bsh
while read -r a1 a2 remote a3 pathnames
do
    ssh -n "$remote" stat -c %n:%y "$pathnames"
done <final-list
```

This further relies on the pathnames in the list of pathnames to be *nice*, i.e. that they contain no embedded whitespace characters or filename globbing characters.  It loops through the lines of `final-list` and calls `stat` on the remote system with the list of pathnames as argument.

The `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` variables read with `read` are dummy variables whose values we aren't interested in.  `a1` will have the value `Node`, `a2` will have the value `Name:`, and `a3` will have the value `Out-ofSync-Filename:`.

The `-n` option to `ssh` is needed to stop `ssh` from reading the data stream that the loop is reading from.

The `stat` call uses the output format `%n:%y` which will produce a list of `pathname:human-readable-modification-time` lines.   Use `%Y` in place of `%y` to get a Unix timestamp instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something like this before. Looping thru every lines:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    host_ip=$(cut -d' ' -f3 <<< "$line")
    file_paths=($( cut -d' ' -f5- <<< "$line" ))
    for f in "${file_paths[@]}"; do
        ssh "$host_ip" "stat $f"
    done
done < input-file
```

Comment: `ssh` must be run with `-n` or with standard input redirected from `/dev/null`, or it will read all lines from `input-file`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see. Didn't know about that. Thanks!